# Saving file in mac using spring boot

Tags: ios, file, spring-boot

I m developing web-service using spring boot. I have two API. In first Api I a allowing user to upload the file. I m saving the file in my system (Mac). Where should I store those file (any specific folder/directory) so that I can return an url and client (iOS) later can access that file using that url.

Comment: the best way to store images on Amazon s3 with open url.. It allows you to share file by hitting the url

Comment: Even for development ?. My project is in early state and i dont want to deploy it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the files in a local directory and you can run a simple http server locally serving on any port .
You can access the file in client side simply using local url(localhost:port/filename).The whole setup has to be local

But the best way to do this is to store the file in s3 bucket or any other cdn(ex-uploadcare)
which can be shared using simple url

Comment: In which folder should I store the file ?

Comment: You can create a folder in your spring boot app directory or any other directory locally. It will serve the purpose if you are not using it as a resource in the spring boot app